# Neo4j Cypher: Unable to define relationships with duplicate records

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So, I have some user event data and would like to create a graph of the same. A snapshot of the data

[image]

Now, the `_id` col has duplicate records but they are actually the same person, however there are multiple `sessionField` records for the same `_id`

What I'd want is something like this:

```
Node A -> sessionNode a1 -> Action Node a11 (with event type as properties, 4 in this case)
       -> sessionNode a2 -> Action Node a21 (with event type as properties, 2 in this case)
Node B -> sessionNode b1 -> Action Node b11 (with event type as properties, 3 in this case)
```

I've tried the following code, but being new to graphs I'm not able to replicate the same:

`session_streams_y` has same data like `_id`

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df_temp.csv' AS users
CREATE (p:Person {nodeId: users._id, sessionId: users.session_streams_y})
CREATE (sn:Session {sessId: users.sessionField, sessionId: users.session_streams_y})

MATCH (p:Person) 
with p as ppl
MATCH (sn:Session) 
WITH ppl, sn as ss
WHERE ppl.sessionId=ss.sessionId
MERGE (ppl)-[:Sessions {sess: 'Has Sessions'}]-(ss)
WITH [ppl,ss] as ns
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(ns) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

This gives something different

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Why are you not using `eventType`, what is the purpose of `session_streams_y`?

Comment: I'm using `session_streams_y` as a common join between 2 nodes, I'm not really sure how to define this relationship without a common key. Also, I'm not sure where will `eventType` fit in my code?

Comment: This `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df_temp.csv' AS users
CREATE (p:Person {nodeId: users.session_streams_y})-[r:hasSession]->(sn:Session {sessId: users.sessionField})` gives me duplicate relation nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df_temp.csv' AS row
MERGE (p:Person {id: row._id})
MERGE (s:Session {id: row.sessionField})
FOREACH(
  x IN CASE WHEN s.eventTypes IS NULL OR NOT row.eventType IN s.eventTypes THEN [1] END |
  SET s.eventTypes = COALESCE(s.eventTypes, []) + row.eventType)
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_SESSION]->(s)
RETURN p, s
```

The resulting `Person` and `Session` nodes would be unique, each `Session` node would have an `eventTypes` list with distinct values, and the appropriate `Person` and `Session` nodes would be connected by a `HAS_SESSION` relationship.

An `Action` node does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: just what i wanted! That's a complex query, couldn't have figured out on my own

Comment: Is this the most optimized way to perform this action? I have around 50K rows and takes forever to run this query. Any workaround for this. I'd like to run some path algorithms on this